Encode a VarInt
Similar question to my previous one, but in reverse. This time I want you to encode an integer into a VarInt.
Background:
I'm not going to assume everyone's seen my previous question, so here is a little background as too what a VarInt is.
A VarInt is a type of signed integer encoding of variable length used a lot in the Minecraft: Java Edition server protocol.
How it works:
A VarInt encodes integers using an array of bytes. The most significant bit of each byte is used as a marker whether to continue to the next byte, while the other 7 bits are all used to encode part of the integer. The integer is encoded in little-endian.
For instance, if I had the integer 12345 (0x00003039)
I would encode it like this:
Arranged in groups of 7 bits: 0111001 | 1100000 | 0000000
Continue bit: 1 0111001 | 0 1100000 | 0 0000000
Final encoding: 10111001 | 01100000 or 0xB9 | 0x60 or 185 | 96
You should treat the input as a signed 32-bit integer. The maximum length you can encode is 5 bytes long.
Here is an un-golfed example function in JavaScript:
function encodeVarInt(value) {
  let result = [];
  while(true) {
    let byte = value & 0x7F;
    value >>>= 7;
    if(value) {
      byte |= 0x80;
      result.push(byte);
    } else {
      result.push(byte);
      break;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

Examples/Test Cases:
0: 0x00
1: 0x01
127: 0x7f
25,565: 0xDD, 0xC7, 0x01
2,097,151: 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x7F
2147483647: 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x07
-1: 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x0F
-2,147,483,648: 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x08
1113983: 0xFF, 0xFE, 0x43
Challenge Rules/Info:

This is a codegolfing challenge! Least amount of bytes wins!
Functions count as a program: f(x)=>y is the same as x=input(); output(y);
Standard loopholes are not allowed
Input can be any form of number, but must be treated as a signed integer
Return value can be any form of array of bytes or bits (e.x. [255, 12], [0,1,0,1], [0x2, 0x3]
Any extra 0 bytes returned will count as 2 bytes each! (trim your final output; e.x. [256, 3, 0, 0] -> [256, 3])


Oops, yeah let me fix that. I cmd c+v'd them from the other post and forgot to remove unnecessary bytes

In your example: 0xB9 != 57. Shouldn't that 57 be 185?

And shouldn't test case 1 be 0x01 instead of 0x81?

Yes, let me do that quickly

Fun Fact: Google's Protobufs also use the same varint encoding

It is, I just messed up highlighting - fixed

C (gcc), 62 59 53 bytes
f(n){printf("%02X ",n&127|!!(n=n+0U>>7)<<7);n&&f(n);}

Try it online!
The literal 0U is an unsigned integer constant. Adding it to n promotes n to an unsigned type.
-6 bytes thanks to @Arnauld!

59 bytes by getting rid of v.

@Arnauld thanks! Does this look correct with the trailing zero's?

Well that question is for the OP. But according to rule #6 which says "trim your final output", I don't think it is.

JavaScript (ES6), 37 bytes
Expects an integer and returns an array of bytes.
f=n=>n>>7?[n&127|128,...f(n>>>7)]:[n]

Try it online!
Commented
f = n =>      // f is a recursive function taking an integer n
n >> 7 ?      // if any bit at position 8 .. 32 of n is set:
  [           //   append:
    n & 127   //     the 7 least significant bits of n
    | 128,    //     with the 8-th bit forced to 1
    ...f(     //     followed by the result of a recursive call:
      n >>> 7 //       pass n right-shifted by 7 positions,
              //       with zero bits shifted in from the left
    )         //     end of recursive call
  ]           //   end of array
:             // else:
  [ n ]       //   append n and stop the recursion


Charcoal, 23 bytes
∨Ｉ⮌Ｅ↨﹪ＮＸ²Ｉ32¹²⁸⁺ι∧κ¹²⁸0

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
      Ｎ                 Input integer
     ﹪                  Modulo
        ²               Literal integer `2`
       Ｘ                Raised to power
          32            Literal string `32`
         Ｉ              Cast to integer
    ↨                   Convert to base
            ¹²⁸         Literal integer `128`
   Ｅ                    Map over list
                ι       Current value
               ⁺        Plus
                  κ     Current index
                 ∧      Logical And
                   ¹²⁸  Literal integer `128`
  ⮌                     Reversed
 Ｉ                      Cast to string
∨                       Logical Or
                      0 Literal string `0`
                        Implicitly print


Python 2, 98 52 50 bytes
f=lambda x:x&-128and[128+x%128]+f(x%2**32>>7)or[x]

Try it online!

48: lambda x:x&-128and[128+x%128]+f(x%2**32>>7)or[x]

Or rather 50, as the f= should count here as far as I know.

C (gcc), 97 bytes

Saved 2 bytes, thanks to @jdt
Saved 16 bytes, thanks to @ceilingcat

Most of the other entries seem to be taking a recursive approach.  I was curious to try a direct approach using x86 instruction intrinsics.
Returns the output in a uint64_t which can be cast to a 0-terminated char array.
#define f(n)_pdep_u64(n+0U,~(~0LU/510))|_pdep_u64((1<<((63-__builtin_clzll(n+0U))/7))-1,~0LU/510)

Try it online!
Compiler Explorer was helpful

You save a couple of bytes with uint64_t f(n){return P(n+=0U,~(~0LU/510))|P((1<<((63-__builtin_clzll(n+0U))/7))-1,~0LU/510);}

@jdt nice - though the output's not right for the -ve inputs

Can you give me an example?

@jdt: https://tio.run/##hZLBbsIwDIbvfQqLaSgZdITRdUiFPcEOXDgxVHVpSi2VFDXphMbKo68zUFjZDsuhqq3Pf@zfke5KyvoGtczKWMHE2Bi1vU@fnetc/jtVoF5Rrr6JVYJawQzCTaw2Yel7TkkSvhdaSJjmu0LZstAwY7o3FfP@nu3Fy3zwOBScf84YG04mjPkjNwzfSsws6lBmH1lGtJhzPnji3B32LyVBVb/nGEOqtnG53jCZa2PhcOGY7rvLpVXW9MHgh6I4U3plUw47B@gQBBgcf5O8AIYwBREAwqQBA@j18EwfzoamtAnrwK142Hb6cJJf4JIHFwYTYCTVhb3YJrxd3VZ41Z1WTeX8fK@JynEOba4j1Kzdt1XGysgos1hS1zuyBNyHoffkjUe@N64C578JD47kCbvocBj8yS0EDfbbg8syC2V8jwTbBVdOyDQq4I6wMrPEsVPMu8fCH@y8uhNIu7IF2d@EvNGrTgM1b0eQMfWXTLJoZWp3HRUynerI4rui6G2Ntdu8zO3Yp3bJ0fv0Gw

This should work: uint64_t f(n){return P(n+0U,~(~0LU/510))|P((1<<((63-__builtin_clzll(n+0U))/7))-1,~0LU/510);}

05AB1E, 13 bytes
žJ%žyвā≠žy*+R

Port of @Neil's Charcoal answer, so make sure to upvote that answer as well!
Try it online or verify all test cases.
Explanation:
  %           # Modulo the (implicit) input-integer by
žJ            # constant 4294967296
     в        # Then convert it from a base-10 integer to a list in base
   žy         # constant 128
      ā       # Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping)
       ≠      # Check for each that it's NOT 1, so we now have a list [0,1,1,1,...]
          *   # Multiply each by
        žy    # constant 128
           +  # Add that to the values at the same positions in the list
            R # Then reverse the list
              # (after which it is output implicitly as result)


Vyxal 3, 12 bytes
₃E%₆yDκ≠₆×+Ṛ

Try it Online!
Port of Charcoal, but there's a one byte built in for 128 so it beats 05ab1e lol

Python 3, 128 bytes
Attempt to get an existing library to do the heavy lifting:
from google.protobuf.internal.encoder import _VarintEncoder as v
def e(n):
 b=bytearray()
 v()(b.extend,n&(2**32-1),0)
 return b

Don't Try it online! - TIO would need google.protobuf modules installed.

Perl 5, 49 bytes
sub f{($n=pop)>>7?($n%128+128,f($n%2**32>>7)):$n}

Try it online!
Just a port of other answers.

F#, 78 bytes
let rec e v=
 let b=v&&&127u
 if b=v then[byte b]else byte(b|||128u)::e(v>>>7)

Try it online!
A function taking a unsigned 32-bit int (treated as a signed int with the same bits) and returning a list of bytes.
